# What happens when we send a random byte via UDP to an opened TCP port at another machine?

Tags: tcp, udp, ip

What happens when we send  a random byte via UDP to an opened TCP port at another machine? Does received PC turns back to sender with any byte or bytes? Also what happens when we try to send a packet to a non opened TCP port at another PC?

Comment: UDP and TCP ports are unrelated. You cannot send an UDP packet to a TCP port. For the other question, the PC receiving garbage in a closed TCP port will simply ignore the packet.

Comment: Try it out. Use `netcat` to send those packets and capture packets with `tcpdump` or `wireshark`.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you describe is impossible. You can't send a UDP datagram to a TCP port at all, whether . Ergo nothing can possibly happen.

Open and closed has nothing to do with it, and neither does local or remote.